# Can (a===b && a!==b) evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to make (a===b && a!==b) evaluate to true?

Thought the answer was no, but I feel like there's probably a trick to it.

Comment: explain with real life example where it is required ?

Comment: They put you into the mindset of type coercion, but that statement even with JS will never make `true`. Test it with some concrete types.

Comment: @Learnonhardway What about race conditions, is there any way for the code not to be executed all at once, making it false? Or is that not possible in JS?

Comment: It's likely that you either misunderstood the question, it was a trick question, or the interviewer was not qualified to give the question. I lean toward the third option.

Comment: @Joe Frambach Not necessarily. This is one elegant way (assuming there is a time for test) to eliminate some candidates. Spending more time than you should on something like this should be punishable, kinda.

Comment: Actually, you should probably question a team that wastes precious interview time on questions like this.

Comment: A single statement like this where `a` and `b` are simple variables is not subject to any race conditions in Javascript.

Comment: `var a= 0
var b= 0

document.write(a===(b && a)!==b)` just throwing out. I know that it should not count but there is just no other way.

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess that makes sense too.

Comment: You should ask the interviewer how many time you faced this scenario while developing any project/product.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

with({
  get a() {
    return i++;
  },
  get b() {
    return j;
  }
}) {
  if (a === b && a !== b)
    console.log("it is work");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This, It works only for `==` not for `===`.

```js
var a = {
    x: 1,
    toString: function () {
        return this.x++;
    }
}
var b = 1;

console.log('Result', (a == b && a != b));

// Another option

var j = {
    x: 1,
    valueOf: function () {
        return this.x++;
    }
}
var k = 1;

console.log('Result', (j == k && j != k));
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it can evaluate to true, but only if you use with

```js
with({
  get a() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  },
  get b() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  }
}) {
  // 25% change of logging true
  console.log(a === b && a !== b);
}
```